# Attach decimal part to an integer

Tags: c#

I need to be able to attach an integer number to another integer as a decimal part, for example:

For numbers `12345` and `12345678` I would want to get: `12345,12345678`

Note: The numbers' length is variable.

I have tried casting numbers to string to measure their length and then divide them accordingly but there must be a more efficient and fast way than this.

Comment: are you sure that your current approach is too slow for your case? Or this question is just about interest of what are the ways to accomplish the task?

Comment: @AlexanderManekovskiy I am performing this operation to a few million numerical pairs and it takes quite a while, I suppose it could go faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very quick and dirty approach, with no error checking at all

```
var total = Double.Parse(string.Concat(left, ",", right));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var left = 12345;
var right = 12345678;
var total = left + (right / Math.Pow(10, Math.Floor(Math.Log10(right)) + 1));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however your solution fails when `right` is zero.

Comment: @DougPeters : I think you'll need to special-case the zero value.

Answer (score 2):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/2506541/1803777, more performance can be obtained without usage of logarithm function.

```
public static decimal GetDivider(int i)
{
    if (i < 10) return 10m;
    if (i < 100) return 100m;
    if (i < 1000) return 1000m;
    if (i < 10000) return 10000m;
    if (i < 100000) return 100000m;
    if (i < 1000000) return 1000000m;
    if (i < 10000000) return 10000000m;
    if (i < 100000000) return 100000000m;
    if (i < 1000000000) return 1000000000m;
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}

int a = 12345;
int b = 12345678;
decimal x = a + b / GetDivider(b);
```

Comment: How does this scale so as to include BigInteger ranges as well? I wouldn't want to write a few hundred `if` lines. Any ideas?

Comment: @DougPeters What type do you plan to use for that number of digits after the decimal? Technically you can make while loop to calculate the divider.

Answer (score 1):

try counting using the following:

```
Math.Floor(Math.Log10(n) + 1);
```

then continue just as you stated.

Source: [How can I get a count of the total number of digits in a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483886/how-can-i-get-a-count-of-the-total-number-of-digits-in-a-number)