# how to find number of digits in assembly 8086?

Tags: math, assembly, x86, x86-16, digits

I am a new assembly programer and I could not succeed in finding how many digits a number has.My purpose is to find factorials.
I program in an emulator of assembly 8086.

Comment: is there an instruction that can do a base10 logarithm of the number?

Comment: Take a look at this for the theory: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6655754/1353098. In practice I don't think there is an instruction for log10. Do you have access to any libraries that might expose this function (like a c library, or a maths library)

Comment: The x87 might come in handy here though. Logs are things that floating point processors are more likely to have. I reckon that `FYL2X` might be the instruction for you.

Comment: Sorry could you elaborate on what you mean by "find factorials"? I'm not sure how finding the number of digits is related.

Comment: Just divide by 10 until you get to zero. Count the times.

Comment: How many bits does an "emulator of assembly 8086" have? The `mul` instruction, with a 16-bit operand, produces a 32-bit result. 21! overflows 64 bits. How high do you need to go?

Comment: @someguy, it helps me to print the number.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way to perform this operation is to use the `bsr` instruction (see this [slides](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/rg1/teaching/advancedc-ws08/script/lecture10.pdf), 20 to 25).

This should make a code like this:

```
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    movl    $1024, %eax ;; pushing the integer (1024) to analyze
    bsrl    %eax, %eax  ;; bit scan reverse (give the smallest non zero index)
    inc     %eax        ;; taking the 0th index into account
```

But, I guess you need the base 10 log and not the base 2... So, here would be the code:

```
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    movl    $1024, %eax ;; pushing the integer (1024) to analyze
    bsrl    %eax, %eax  ;; bit scan reverse (give the smallest non zero index)
    inc     %eax        ;; taking the 0th index into account

    pushl   %eax        ;; saving the previous result on the stack

    fildl   (%esp)      ;; loading the previous result to the FPU stack (st(0))
    fldlg2              ;; loading log10(2) on the FPU stack
    fmulp   %st, %st(1) ;; multiplying %st(0) and %st(1) and storing result in %st(0)

    ;; We need to set the FPU control word to 'round-up' (and not 'round-down')
    fstcw  -2(%esp)      ;; saving the old FPU control word
    movw   -2(%esp), %ax ;; storing the FPU control word in %ax
    andw   $0xf3ff, %ax  ;; removing everything else
    orw    $0x0800, %ax  ;; setting the proper bit to '1'
    movw   %ax, -4(%esp) ;; getting the value back to memory
    fldcw  -4(%esp)      ;; setting the FPU control word to the proper value

    frndint              ;; rounding-up

    fldcw  -2(%esp)      ;; restoring the old FPU control word

    fistpl (%esp)        ;; loading the final result to the stack
    popl   %eax          ;; setting the return value to be our result

    leave
    ret
```

I am curious to know if somebody can find better than that ! Indeed, using SSE instructions might help.

Comment: Worth mentioning that BSR requires 386, so it wouldn't be usable for future readers who were stuck with the 8086 restriction mentioned in the question.  (Some schools teach asm using emu8086, unfortunately.)  Knowing the number of significant base-2 digits gets you within 1 of the right number of base-10 digits, so you can make a lookup table of base-10 digits and a compare threshold to increment that by 1 or not.

Comment: FP tricks: instead of changing the rounding mode, you could maybe subtract 32 or something to make it negative, then convert (with truncation) to integer, e.g. SSE `cvttss2si eax, xmm0`, or SSE3 `fisttp` and undo the bias.  You can test it for all 32 or 64 possible BSR results; if necessary tweak the log10(2) constant up or down by 1ulp if the rounding error is in the wrong direction and pushing it up past the next integer when it shouldn't be.  (With SSE, you'd have to define your own log10_2 constant in memory anyway.)