# non-'constexpr' function std::to_string(int) in a consteval lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, compiler-errors, c++20, consteval

I'm having trouble with `std::to_string()` in the following lambda function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


inline constexpr int a_global_constant { 12345 };


int main( )
{
    auto calculateMsgLength = [ ] ( ) consteval -> std::size_t
    {
        std::string str1 { "Part 1 " };
        std::string str2 { "Part 2 " };
        std::string msg { str1 + str2 /*+ std::to_string( a_global_constant )*/ };

        // The complete message should look like this: Part 1 Part 2 12345

        return msg.length( );
    };

    constexpr std::size_t msgLength { calculateMsgLength( ) };

    std::cout << "Message length == " << msgLength << '\n';
}
```

The above code doesn't compile on my ***GCC v11.2*** therefore I had to use ***GCC (trunk)*** at the [**Compiler Explorer**](https://godbolt.org/z/qjYMfWcEM) to compile it.

However, just by uncommenting the call to `std::to_string()` it doesn't compile:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:19:61: error: 'main()::<lambda()>' called in a constant expression
   19 |         constexpr std::size_t msgLength { calculateMsgLength( ) };
      |                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
<source>:10:35: note: 'main()::<lambda()>' is not usable as a 'constexpr' function because:
   10 |         auto calculateMsgLength = [ ] ( ) consteval -> std::size_t
      |                                   ^
<source>:10:35: error: call to non-'constexpr' function 'std::string std::__cxx11::to_string(int)'
.
.
.
```

Is `std::to_string` going to be made `constexpr` in STL sometime in the near future? Or should I look for an alternative way for doing this? What is an alternative to `std::to_string`?

Comment: Possibly [relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62596471/10871073)?

Comment: Or perhaps this is useful? [Finding the number of digits of an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655754/finding-the-number-of-digits-of-an-integer)

Comment: @Adrian Mole Yes, might be useful.

Comment: `std::to_string` is specified in terms of `sprintf`. While it doesn't have to actually be implemented via `sprintf`, it more than likely shares internals with it at the very least across major implementations. Making *that* `constexpr` will be a major pain to standard library and/or compiler vendors. Don't expect it soon.

Answer (score 2):

> Is `std::to_string` going to be made constexpr in STL sometime in the near future? Or should I look for an alternative way for doing this? What is an alternative to `std::to_string`?

I'm not aware of plans for `std::to_string`, but `std::to_chars` (and `std::from_chars`) for integral types will likely be `constexpr` in C++23 by way of [P2291](https://wg21.link/p2291). Not sure why not `std::to_string`, at least for the integral types.

That said, if all you want is to convert a base-10 integer to a `std::string` at compile time, that's a fairly easy algorithm to write. The only tricky part is handling `INT_MIN` (since you can't just negate the argument if it's negative, that would overflow). But since this is a `constexpr` function, if you get it wrong, it's a compile error, which makes it a lot easier to get it right.

Comment: "*Not sure why not std::to_string*" probably because of locale issues.

Comment: @NicolBolas Just for floating point tho, right?