# C++ - how to find the length of an integer

Tags: c++, count, numbers, integer, digits

I'm trying to find a way to find the length of an integer (number of digits) and then place it in an integer array. The assignment also calls for doing this without the use of classes from the STL, although the program spec does say we can use "common C libraries" (gonna ask my professor if I can use cmath, because I'm assuming log10(num) + 1 is the easiest way, but I was wondering if there was another way).

Ah, and this doesn't have to handle negative numbers. Solely non-negative numbers.

I'm attempting to create a variant "MyInt" class that can handle a wider range of values using a dynamic array. Any tips would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: @KerrekSB Actually I think he means the total unsigned value. That would be 2 to the power of ( sizeof( int ) * 8 - 1 ), right? EDIT: Nevermind.

Comment: The number of digits in a decimal integer is (log(number) / log(10)).

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use a "Big Number" Library.  Search the web for "c++ big number library".

Comment: `int len = n?0:1; while (n) { len++, n/=10 }`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Thomas, but this is actually an assignment for class, and a little bit of a programming challenge for a newbie!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The number of digits of an integer `n` in any base is trivially obtained by dividing until you're done:

```
unsigned int number_of_digits = 0;

do {
     ++number_of_digits; 
     n /= base;
} while (n);
```

Comment: There is no reason to use this solution as log10-based solutions are much better.

Comment: @tleb: better in what sense? Have you compared the two approaches?

Comment: Like this better than the `log10` solution but would prefer a more explicit `while (n != 0)` for readability. Still, worth an upvote.

Answer (score 44):

Not necessarily the most efficient, but one of the shortest and most readable using C++:

```
std::to_string(num).length()
```

Comment: and this solution meets this requirement. It additionally handle negative numbers. xD

Answer (score 29):

There is a much better way to do it

```
    #include<cmath>
    ...
    int size = trunc(log10(num)) + 1
....
```

works for int and decimal

> UPDATE 27/07/2023

we can use this line to check for negatives and 0 values.

```
int size = num == 0 ? 1 : (num < 0 ? static_cast<int>(log10(std::abs(num))) + 1 : static_cast<int>(log10(num)) + 1);
```

Comment: I like this (hence the upvote), just unfortunate it doesn't work for the number zero ...

Comment: I agree this is a really good answer and deserves the upvote. If your use case does not expect or has safeguards against zero, this is the best solution.

Comment: But when num==0 you have a problem. 
log10(0) is undefined

Answer (score 11):

If you can use C libraries then one method would be to use [sprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf), e.g.

```
#include <cstdio>

char s[32];

int len = sprintf(s, "%d", i);
```

Comment: You could use [snprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)(nullptr, 0, "%d", i);` and not need `s`.

Comment: This also will not work for 128-bit integers. The `nullptr` solution from @Tony will fix that.

Answer (score 9):

*"I mean the number of digits in an integer, i.e. "123" has a length of 3"*

```
int i = 123;

// the "length" of 0 is 1:
int len = 1;

// and for numbers greater than 0:
if (i > 0) {
    // we count how many times it can be divided by 10:
    // (how many times we can cut off the last digit until we end up with 0)
    for (len = 0; i > 0; len++) {
        i = i / 10;
    }
}

// and that's our "length":
std::cout << len;
```

outputs `3`

Answer (score 4):

Closed formula for the longest `int` (I used `int` here, but works for any signed integral type):

```
1 + (int) ceil((8*sizeof(int)-1) * log10(2))
```

Explanation:

```
                  sizeof(int)                 // number bytes in int
                8*sizeof(int)                 // number of binary digits (bits)
                8*sizeof(int)-1               // discount one bit for the negatives
               (8*sizeof(int)-1) * log10(2)   // convert to decimal, because:
                                              // 1 bit == log10(2) decimal digits
    (int) ceil((8*sizeof(int)-1) * log10(2))  // round up to whole digits
1 + (int) ceil((8*sizeof(int)-1) * log10(2))  // make room for the minus sign
```

For an `int` type of 4 bytes, the result is 11. An example of 4 bytes `int` with 11 decimal digits is: "-2147483648".

If you want the number of decimal digits of some `int` value, you can use the following function:

```
unsigned base10_size(int value)
{
    if(value == 0) {
        return 1u;
    }

    unsigned ret;
    double dval;
    if(value > 0) {
        ret = 0;
        dval = value;
    } else {
        // Make room for the minus sign, and proceed as if positive.
        ret = 1;
        dval = -double(value);
    }

    ret += ceil(log10(dval+1.0));

    return ret;
}
```

I tested this function for the whole range of `int` in g++ 9.3.0 for x86-64.

Comment: `ceil(log10(var+1))` will fail for INT_MAX

Comment: This is not reliable, the max value of type will fail. Totally agree with bricklore. I prefer std::to_string(num).length() as Riot said.

Comment: The problem of `INT_MAX` was fixed by converting to `double` before adding 1.

Answer (score 3):

```
int intLength(int i) {
    int l=0;
    for(;i;i/=10) l++;
    return l==0 ? 1 : l;
}
```

Here's a tiny efficient one

Comment: you have to save the case i == 0. which is also 1 and current function returns 0;

Answer (score 2):

Being a computer nerd and not a maths nerd I'd do:

```
char buffer[64];
int len = sprintf(buffer, "%d", theNum);
```

Comment: Which will crash spectacularly when 256-bit integers become available :-)

Answer (score 2):

Would this be an efficient approach? Converting to a string and finding the length property?

```
int num = 123  
string strNum = to_string(num); // 123 becomes "123"
int length = strNum.length(); // length = 3
char array[3]; // or whatever you want to do with the length
```

Comment: Not very efficient though.

Answer (score 2):

How about (works also for 0 and negatives):

```
int digits( int x ) { 
    return ( (bool) x * (int) log10( abs( x ) ) + 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to find using log, it works always

```
int len = ceil(log10(num))+1;
```

Comment: For num==50, log10(50) ~= 1.7, ceil(1.7) = 2 plus 1 gives 3. Rounding up with ceil is the wrong approach.

Comment: You should truncate instead of rounding up

Answer (score 1):

Code for finding Length of int and decimal number:

```
#include<iostream>
    #include<cmath>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int len,num;
        cin >> num;
        len = log10(num) + 1;
        cout << len << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    //sample input output
    /*45566
    5

    Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 3.292 s
    Press any key to continue.
    */
```

Answer (score 0):

**There are no inbuilt functions in C/C++ nor in STL for finding length of integer but there are few ways by which it can found** 
Here is a sample C++ code to find the length of an integer, it can be written in a function for reuse.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  long long int n;
  cin>>n;
  unsigned long int integer_length = 0;

  while(n>0)
  {    
   integer_length++;
   n = n/10; 
  }
 
  cout<<integer_length<<endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Here is another way, convert the integer to string and find the length, it accomplishes same with a single line:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        long long int n;
    cin>>n;
    unsigned long int integer_length = 0;
    
    // convert to string
    integer_length = to_string(n).length();
    
    cout<<integer_length<<endl;

    return 0;
    }
```

**Note: Do include the `cstring` header file**

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use without any libraries in c++ is

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num, length = 0;
    cin >> num;
    while(num){
        num /= 10;
        length++;
    }
    cout << length;
}
```

Comment: This does not really add anything new to what other answers (including the accepted one) have proposed.

Answer (score 0):

You can  also use this function:

```
int countlength(int number)
{
    static int count = 0;
    if (number > 0)
    {
        count++;
        number /= 10;
        countlength(number);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73786066/10871073) to multiple questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <math.h>

int intLen(int num)
{        
    if (num == 0 || num == 1)
        return 1;
    else if(num < 0)
        return ceil(log10(num * -1))+1;
    else
        return ceil(log10(num));
}
```

Comment: Check your boundary values. `intLen(10)` returns 1.

Answer (score -2):

Most efficient code to find length of a number.. counts zeros as well, note "n" is the number to be given.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,len= 0;
    cin>>n;
while(n!=0)
    {
       len++;
       n=n/10;
    }
    cout<<len<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This provides nothing that the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22649020/545127) does not provide.

Comment: Yes. 14 answers already and this isn't any different to many of them.