# String.length() or String.size() returns number with "\x" (\x5)

Tags: c++, string, count, int

I was trying to get number of characters in my `int` value. In order to due so I have converted `int` to `string` and took `.length()`. Conversion from `int` to `string` looks good, but when I check value of `.length()` seems like there is additional char (console shows that there is value "\x5"). Do you know where there could be an issue?

I tried to `.size()` as well, same results. I used this function before (`.length()`) and actually I have received correct results.

```
int main() {

int roz = 703;

string dlus = to_string(roz);

string dlus1 = dlus.size();

int dlu = atoi(dlus1.c_str());

}
```

Results:

```
dlus1 = "3" 

dlu = "3"
```

Comment: try size_t dlus1 = dlus.size();

Comment: If this compiles you probably need to turn on `-Wall` because assigning a number to a string is not a valid operation.

Comment: Since `string::size()` returns a number, not a string, you could try something like: `string dlus1 = to_string(dlus.size());`

Comment: @zneak clang gives me "error: no viable conversion" for that assignment of `size()` to `std::string`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648978/c-how-to-find-the-length-of-an-integer

Comment: And https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/bugprone-string-integer-assignment.html

Comment: What compiler gave this result? I can't reproduce this on gcc, clang and VS. I did see some conversions from int to char, but with +=.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want something like this:

```
int main()
{
    int number = 703;
    size_t count = std::to_string(number).length();
    std::cout << count;
}
```

But this is duplicate question. More info you can find here: [C++ - how to find the length of an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648978/c-how-to-find-the-length-of-an-integer)

Answer (score 1):

To add to the explanation here, as what is happening. First, I could not reproduce your issue, but I have a variation that doesn't warn on clang and gcc but is still not what you want:

```
std::string dlus = std::to_string(roz);
dlus += dlus.size();
```

Here, it uses an available overload:

```
basic_string& operator+=( CharT ch );
```

and it converts the integer silently to a char. Even with `-Wall`, it is not tagged as bad.

Now, that's where [clang-tidy comes in](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/bugprone-string-integer-assignment.html). With this rule, this code is flagged as possibly wrong, and it indicates that you should use `std::to_string` to properly convert the number to a string before appending it.

If we know which compiler you were using, then we can also figure out which constructor was used in this instance.