# Efficient way of checking the length of a double in C++

Tags: c++, math

Say I have a number, `100000`, I can use some simple maths to check its size, i.e. `log(100000) -> 5` (base 10 logarithm).  Theres also another way of doing this, which is quite slow. `std::string num = std::to_string(100000)`, `num.size()`. Is there an way to mathematically determine the length of a number? (not just 100000, but for things like 2313455, 123876132.. etc)

Comment: Do you mean a mathematical way _other_ than the base 10 logarithm?

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't get a straight `5` doing a base 10 log on `250000`. @NathanPierson

Comment: Maybe you could use the modulo operator on the number until it equals 0 and check how many times it took? That's more programmatic than mathematical, though...

Comment: The best way can't be better than O(n).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ - how to find the length of an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648978/c-how-to-find-the-length-of-an-integer)

Comment: Actually, the integer value of a base 10 logarithm on a number might work.

Comment: You can do some trickery I think with the floating point standard. Using pointers you can get the exponent of the number and after that you only need a const division if I am correct

Comment: @Yves Using the floating point standard with ptr manipulation can get the exponent and that yields O(1) I think

Comment: @Lala5th How would you do that? The first 10 binary digits after the sign bit?

Comment: @asjhdbashjdbasjhdbhjb I think for single precision it is the first 8 bit. There is some maths you need to do on it (subtraciton and division) but after that it shoud work for values > 1

Comment: Is it ok if the size is in powers of 2 instead of powers of 10? Getting the size in powers of 2 is absolutely trivial. Getting the size as a power of 10 is trickier.

Comment: @asjhdbashjdbasjhdbhjb Added a rough proof of concept below. For double precision it can be adapted(i.e. 23 -> 52 and 127->1023)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use `ceil`? It rounds up to the nearest whole number - you can just wrap that around your log function, and add a check afterwards to catch the fact that a power of 10 would return 1 less than expected.

Comment: would screw up with a double like 9.9999997. Not sure if that's on the table or not, though.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution to the problem using single precision floating point numbers in O(1):

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main(){
    float x = 500; // to be converted
    uint32_t f;
    std::memcpy(&f, &x, sizeof(uint32_t)); // Convert float into a manageable int
    uint8_t exp = (f & (0b11111111 << 23)) >> 23; // get the exponent
    exp -= 127; // floating point bias
    exp /= 3.32; // This will round but for this case it should be fine (ln2(10))
    std::cout << std::to_string(exp) << std::endl;
}
```

For a number in scientific notation `a*10^e` this will return e (when `1<=a<10`), so the length of the number (if it has an absolute value larger than 1), will be `exp + 1`.

For double precision this works, but you have to adapt it (bias is 1023 I think, and bit alignment is different. Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format))

This only works for floating point numbers, though so probably not very useful in this case. The efficiency in this case relative to the logarithm will also be determined by the speed at which `int -> float` conversion can occur.

Edit:

I just realised the question was about double. The modified result is:

```cpp
int16_t getLength(double a){
    uint64_t bits;
    std::memcpy(&bits, &a, sizeof(uint64_t));
    int16_t exp = (f >> 52) & 0b11111111111; // There is no 11 bit long int so this has to do
    exp -= 1023;
    exp /= 3.32;
    return exp + 1;
}
```

There are some changes so that it behaves better (and also less shifting).

You can also use `frexp()` to get the exponent without bias.

Comment: Why not use `frexp()` for clarity?

Comment: @user1095108 I didn't know that existed, but yeah you can use that

Comment: you can fix your answer, it's better than the bit-hacks. Or at least the second answer, which is an edit anyway.

Comment: @user1095108 `frexp()` probably does the same, or something similar. I don't want to replace my answer with just use `frexp()` because it a) doesn't change the fact that some floating point pointer hacking happens and b) it just abstracts away the reason why it works, and how.

Comment: it would provide an alternative to what you provide in answer number 1.

Answer (score 0):

If the number is whole, keep dividing by 10, until you're at 0. You'd have to divide 100000 6 times, for example. For the fractional part, you need to keep multiplying by 10 until `trunc(f) == f`.

Comment: that seems quite slow, comparatively, to the logarithm solution

Comment: is log() fast? I didn't know it was that fast. Anyway, you can write your own in which case you will have muls instead of divs. We would have to make a proper comparison. For bignums floats are inappropriate anyway.

Comment: @asjhdbashjdbasjhdbhjb For low N, the simple and slow algorithms tend outperform smarter algorithms because the added smarts you have to put into the algorithm to get from, say, O(N) to O(Log (N)) often have costs that offset the gains of the smarter algorithm. The most you get out of a typical `double` implementation is about 300 digits, which may or may not be peanuts, depending on the speed of the `log` implementation. 6 digits is laughable and will almost certainly compute faster than `log`.

Comment: At 300, both may be more expensive than `to_string`