# Buffer size to convert double to char* in C

Tags: c, string, double

In order to convert a `double` (or `float`, `int`, `long`) to `char*` in C we can use

i) `sprintf()`

ii) functions like `itoa()`, `ftoa()`

But all these functions expect a buffer as a parameter.
What should be size of the buffer in each case so that the maximum integer or the maximum precision float/double can be converted ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068397/finding-the-length-of-an-integer-in-c See if this helps. Don't know about floats however.

Comment: There is no standard `ftoa` function.

Answer (score 3):

`snprintf` can be used to determine the size, with a 0 argument as the size:

```
double x = 42;
const char fmt[] = "%f";
int size = snprintf(0, 0, fmt, x);
if(size < 0) { /* handle error */ }
char buf[size+1];
sprintf(buf, fmt, x);
```

The C standard requires `snprintf` with a 0 size argument to work. Note, though, that some older implementations don't conform (e.g. Glibc until version 2.0.6 returns -1 if the output was truncated instead of the number of characters that would have been written, according to the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf)).

The error checking above may be useless, the only possible error which can occur is an encoding error.

You shouldn't change the locale between the `snprintf` and the `sprintf` call, the locale may affect the size. The `sprintf` can be replaced by a `snprintf` call again if intervening locale changes are a concern, but then you probably want to allocate the memory via `malloc`, and then `realloc` while necessary. [Thanks, [Chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux)!]

Under Glibc, there is also [`asprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf) which allocates the buffer itself. Don't forget to free it afterwards. [Thanks to [Abligh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3177124/abligh)!]

Comment: extremely pedantic point: C11 doesn't require this to work as VLAs are optional .

Comment: Concerning `locale` change (or if x may be `volatile`),  suggest calling `snprintf()` the 2nd time too.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Yes, I've used them here because it's one of the few cases where I find VLAs (not pointers to VLAs) useful: You haven't got a good upper bound for the length but you know it won't be "huge". It's basic C knowledge how to do it without them, and not really related to the question, so I didn't mention it.

Comment: @chux: And then do what? In a debug built, you could `abort`. Either way, I think it's best to document the function to not accept locale changes during its execution. Alternatively, `malloc` and `realloc` in a loop until everything worked. But yes, probably good to mention, I'll edit later, I don't have the time currently.

Comment: Under `glibc` you can use `asprintf` to allocate a buffer of the correct size.

Comment: I think asprintf is the right choice.  Memory allocation is taken care of.

Answer (score 1):

Make the buffer just large enough. A double has about 15 places plus exponent and signs. A buffer `char buffer[25]` should do.

Comment: And what exactly is "large enough"? This depends on architecture etc. Also, it'll never be minimum possible value (if it matters).

Comment: As long as the architecture uses IEEE floating point the max _length_ of a double in string representation should be rather constant. Just print pi * -1.0 * 1e-15 as a string and count characters, add one for security and one for `\0`

Comment: It's really bad advice to do size calculations that sloppily. `%f`, for example, prints 6 digits after the `.` by default, what makes `char[25]` too small for some IEEE double values.

Comment: @mafso Sadly, true. So my answer isn't helpful in the general case.

Comment: If you get a nice formula for the size akin to `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT / 3 + 2` for `int`, I'll consider this a very helpful answer. But I don't know of a somewhat reasonable way to get an upper bound, especially because I don't know if the length of the decimal point has an upper bound across all locales (maybe `MB_LEN_MAX`?). `DECIMAL_DIG` from `<float.h>` (and other macros from there) might be helpful.

Comment: this is exactly the kind of thinking that leads to exploitable software (unless you also use `snprintf` to print, that is)

Comment: @mafso To uniquely print every `double` in exponential notation, code needs to print at least `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` digits.  `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` is in `<float.h>`.  [Ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839658/printf-width-specifier-to-maintain-precision-of-floating-point-value)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to limit the length with the `%f` specifier, as the length parameter is a minimum, not a maximum. So large values take as many characters as their exponent, not counting the decimals.

For example, `"%f.10", 1.e20f` yields `100000002004087730000.0000000000`.

In this respect, `sprintf` is extremely unsafe (should be banned), prefer `snprintf`.

Comment: Note: In `C` locale, the `"%f"` length limit is `DBL_MAX_10_EXP + 9` (+1 for `'\0'`).  Agree about `sprintf()` concerns.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a `double` to a string and using `sprintf()`, the buffer size needs depends on the format specifier.

Note that the buffers below are fixed at compile time, not VLA.

```
//       -   digits               .   000000 \0
char buf[1 + 1 + DBL_MAX_10_EXP + 1 + 6 + 1];
sprintf(buf, "%f", x);

//       -   digit.digits          e   -  xxxx \0
char buf[1 + 2 + DBL_DECIMAL_DIG + 1 + 1 + 4 + 1];
sprintf(buf, "%.*e", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, x);

// Others: %0.100f %a %*.*E etc.
```

But `printf()` functions consider their `locale` so additional characters *could* show up.  Suggest oversizing buffer to 2x the expected size, using `snprintf()` and then sleeping well at night.

```
//       -   digit.digits          e   -  xxxx \0
char buf[(1 + 2 + DBL_DECIMAL_DIG + 1 + 1 + 4 + 1)*2];
int len = snprintf(buf, "%.*e", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, x);
if (len < 0 || len >= sizeof buf) {
  Handle_Insanity();
}
```

Ref: [Printf width specifier to maintain precision of floating-point value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839658/printf-width-specifier-to-maintain-precision-of-floating-point-value)