# Output indentation in C

Tags: c, printf, width

Basically I want to print something like this:

```
Process No.(Size)    Block No.(Size)
1(200)               3(300)
2(3)                 1(50)
3(1000)              4(1200)
```

Since the spacing is variable, how to do it by the width specifier in `%d`?

```c
printf("%d(%d)%d(%d)",processNo,processSize,blockNo,blockSize)
```

Where to put the spacing value?

Comment: You can only specify a field width if you know it. And as your spacing depends on 2 variables, you only know it after printing `processNo` and `processSize`. Therefore I don't see a way to do this in a single function call. You might print first part into a buffer and then adjust according to `strlen` of that buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first print each 'field' of your table into a character string, then print each such field string using a left-justified, fixed-width format specifier. The latter is accomplished using the `-` flag and a `width` value in the `%s` format specifier (i.e., `-n%s`).

The following code displays what you require (I have used the fields to hold both the column titles and each row of data, but this is an 'optional extra').

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Test data ...
    int procNo[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int procSize[3] = { 200, 3, 1000};
    int blockNo[3] = { 3, 1, 4 };
    int blockSize[3] = { 300, 50, 1200 };

    char procField[32] = "Process No.(Size)";
    char blockField[32] = "Block No.(Size)";

    // Print rubric ...
    printf("%-22s%-22s\n", procField, blockField);

    // Print data rows ...
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        // Write each field to string ...
        snprintf(procField, sizeof(procField), "%d(%d)", procNo[i], procSize[i]);
        snprintf(blockField, sizeof(blockField), "%d(%d)", blockNo[i], blockSize[i]);
        // ... then print fields as left-justified, fixed-length fields
        printf("%-22s%-22s\n", procField, blockField);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While it's unlikely to be an issue with these string sizes, I would use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf` to make it bit more robust.

Comment: @user694733 Fair point (I can get a bit lazy with `sprintf` and cousins). See edit.

Answer (score 2):

`printf` has two seldom-used features that allow this to be done simply and directly.

The first feature is the return value from `printf`. Yes, `printf` actually returns something, and it's the number of characters that were printed. Consider the following two lines of code:

```
int width = printf("Process No.(Size)    ");
int used  = printf("%d(%d)", procNum[i], procSize[i]);
```

The first line prints the column header, and sets variable `width` to the number of characters in that header. The second line prints the process information, and sets variable `used` to the number of characters needed to print the two numbers, and the parentheses. So the number of space characters required between the end of the process information, and the beginning of the block information, is simply `width - used`.

The second feature is the variable field width specifier. From the man page: *"A field width or precision, or both, may be indicated by an asterisk `'*'` [...] In this case, an `int` argument supplies the field width or precision."*  Consider the following line of code:

```
printf("%*s", width - used, "");
```

The code is using the `"%s"` conversion specifier to print a string, but the string `""` is empty, so normally nothing would be printed. But we've used an asterisk as the field width. So the argument *before* the string (`width - used`) supplies the field width. The string will be padded with spaces to fill that width.

Note that if `width - used` is less than 1, the code should set the field width to 1, so that at least one space is inserted between the process information, and the block information.

Putting it all together, the code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define max(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))

int main(void)
{
    int procNum[]   = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int procSize[]  = { 200, 3, 1000 };
    int blockNum[]  = { 3, 1, 4 };
    int blockSize[] = { 300, 50, 1200};

    int width = printf("Process No.(Size)    ");    // print first column header, and save the width
    printf("Block No.(Size)\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int used = printf("%d(%d)", procNum[i], procSize[i]);      // print process information, and save the number of characters used
        printf("%*s%d(%d)\n", max(width - used, 1), "", blockNum[i], blockSize[i]);   // print spaces followed by the block information
    }
}
```

Comment: another perfect answer, and i think we can omit the `#define` line and replace `max(width - used, 1)` with `width - used + 1` for a more simple and shorter code

Comment: @mr.loop The reason for the `max` macro is to handle the case where the 1st column header is not wide enough for the information being printed. To see an example, change the header to `"ProcInfo "` and `procNum[0]` to 123456789 and `procSize[0]` to `1000000000`. In that case, `width` is 9 and `used` is 21, so `width - used + 1` would be -11, but `max(width - used, 1)` is 1.

Answer (score 0):

See the 'Width field' subsection in [printf format string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string) for an example of how width is passed as an argument to `printf`.

I got the width algorithm from [Finding the length of an integer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068397/finding-the-length-of-an-integer-in-c).

I tested my code at [Code Chef](https://www.codechef.com/ide). If you intend to compile this code with `gcc`, you will need the `-lm` option to bring in the library for `math.h`. See [How to compile a C program that uses math.h?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332884/how-to-compile-a-c-program-that-uses-math-h).

If you need a different table header, you could adjust the constants 11 in `printspaces(11-w)` & 5 in `printspaces(5-w)` till data aligns with the header.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int width(int v){
    return floor(log10(abs(v))) + 1;
}

int printspaces(int s){
    int x;
    for (x=0;x<s;x++)
        printf(" ");
}

int main(void){
    int i,j,w;
    int a[3][4] = {{1,200,3,300},{2,3,1,50},{3,1000,4,1200}};
    //int a[3][4] = {{10,200,37,3000},{278,3565,1131,50},{390,100,4567,1200}};
    char *separator[4]  = {"","","","\n"};
    printf("Process No.(Size)   Block No.(Size)\n");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for (j=0;j<4;j++){
            w = width(a[i][j]);
            if (j%2==0){
                printspaces(11-w);
                printf("%*d%s",w,a[i][j],separator[j]);
            }
            else{
                printf("(%*d)",w,a[i][j]);
                printspaces(5-w);
                printf("%s",separator[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the results (for the two example arrays in the code):

```
int a[3][4] = {{1,200,3,300},{2,3,1,50},{3,1000,4,1200}};

Process No.(Size)   Block No.(Size)
          1(200)            3(300)  
          2(3)              1(50)   
          3(1000)           4(1200) 


int a[3][4] = {{10,200,37,3000},{278,3565,1131,50},{390,100,4567,1200}};

Process No.(Size)   Block No.(Size)
         10(200)           37(3000) 
        278(3565)        1131(50)   
        390(100)         4567(1200)
```